# Como alinhar divs lado a lado

Tags: css

ja tentei de tudo que e jeito deixar essas div alinhadinhas, no desktop elas ficam perfeitas, a cada linha tem 4 div vizualizando do computador, agora no android era pra mostra 3 div por linhas, porem nao deu muito certo, e o codigo e o mesmo utilizado pra desktop, so mudei o numero de exibicao pra 3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="cartaz">
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**desktop**

```
.cartaz{
   float: left;
   margin: 0% 2% 0% 0%;
   padding: 0% 0% 2% 0%;
   width: 78%;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
li .mini-box{
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 0%;
  width: 23.5%;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: #4DAE52;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
li:nth-child(-n+4) .mini-box{
  margin: 0 2% 0 0;
}
li:nth-child(4n) .mini-box{
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
li:last-child .mini-box{margin: 0%;}
```

**android**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){
  li .mini-box{
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    width: 31.9%;
    background-color: purple
  }
  li:nth-child(-n+3) .mini-box{
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    background-color: orange
  }
  li:nth-child(3n) .mini-box{
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
    background-color: gray
  }
  li:last-child .mini-box{margin: 0%;background-color: red}
}
```

Comment: Coloque o CSS completo para que se possa reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @Sam sei que parece estar imcompleto, mais e isso ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque a regra `li .mini-box` por `li:nth-child(n) .mini-box` no `@media` pois ele tem mais força que a regra `li:nth-child(4n) .mini-box` que está definindo a margem direita de alguns elementos fora do `@media`. O `(n)` irá aplicar as propriedades a todos os elementos do seletor.

> Aumentei o breakpoint de 360px para 660px para exemplificar e poder
>   visualizar aqui.

```css
ul, li{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none
}

li .mini-box{
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 0%;
  width: 23.5%;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: #4DAE52;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
li:nth-child(-n+4) .mini-box{
  margin: 0 2% 0 0;
}
li:nth-child(4n) .mini-box{
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
li:last-child .mini-box{margin: 0%;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 660px){
  li:nth-child(n) .mini-box{
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    width: 31.9%;
    background-color: purple
  }
  li:nth-child(-n+3) .mini-box{
    /* margin: 0 2% 0 0; removido */
    background-color: orange
  }

  li:nth-child(3n) .mini-box{
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
    background-color: gray
  }
  li:last-child .mini-box{margin: 0;background-color: red}

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>

    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="mini-box"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```